# how to read message from Kafka topic based on response from another topic

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka

I have 2 topics in Kafka: MetaData and MasterData.
And I am reading data in real time using Kafka Listners. There are 2 scenarios:

1. I have to read MetaData topic first and then MasterData topic.
2. There could also be a possibility that no new msg comes in MetaData topic, but a message is inserted in MasterData topic. In such as case consumption from MasterData topic should go ahead.

Ant suggestions how to achieve this??

Comment: What is the criteria to say: OK it seems nothing comes in MetaData, I go on in MasterData? I mean, you are in a streaming environment. Do you want to wait for a given amount of time?

Comment: @JanHeld No, I don't want to wait. The messages are to be read in real time. MetaData basically provides metaData for tables while MasterData provides values. So if there is any change in table structure then, I will have message in the Metadata topic and it should be read first. But if there is no change in tables then, no msg will come in MetaData. Only new values will come in MasterData topic.

Comment: I updated my answer. Maybe we can chat, which would be easier to clarify, what you really try to achieve.

Comment: sure we can chat. but how?

Comment: I opened a chat room here: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207335/clarificaton-on-kafka-question

Comment: ok. So you got the idea right. What I had in mind was to use Acks to identify if msg has been read from MetaData topic, so that I can proceed to read msg from next topic. But there is no way for me to know if no new msg comes in metaData topic

Comment: I don't have enough rep to enter chat.

Comment: Exactly. Can you tell me, what do you want to achieve, I mean "why" do you need to read the meta topic first?

Comment: In my application the table creation/modification/deletion needs to be dynamic. Hence the metadata topic provides list of tables and columns.

Comment: Okay, so you have a database like system, and the meta data from the kafka topic is used to adjust the table structure. Then the actual data comes into the master kafka topic which you then want to insert into the table. In other words: You want to define the structure of your data using kafka, Correct?

Comment: who is the producer for these topics? as in, who is sending data to these topics?

Comment: @JanHeld yes. It's somewhat like that.

Comment: @abi_pat there is a separate producer service which sends the msgs to these 2 topics.

Comment: I want to understand the producer pattern is it like - 09:00:01 - sending masterdata , 09:00:02 - sending masterdata, 09:00:03 sending metadata, 9:00:04 - sending masterdata, 09:00:05 - sending masterdata

Comment: producer calls stored procedure with gives only changes in the results.So if there is no change in table structure, no msg will be created in MetaData table while if any  changes observed in masterdata then it is inserted into MasterData topic.

Comment: I updated my original answer. Hope it's a bit helpful.

Comment: @abi_pat yes. If there is some data to be put into MetaData then, the producer will be placing that first and then msg in masterData.

Comment: @AkshayPrakash if the data is going to be sequential (as in my comment) you can use single topic and then you don't need to wait or check anything else. insert all the messages in single topic and you can have some identifier to differentiate between metadata and masterdata. Similarly you can write code to handle these two messages differently.

Comment: @abi_pat It occurred to me as well, but that is not the requirement. Hence cannot change it. I'll have to read from different topics. Infact there are a no. of more topics to be read but here in question I kept it simple.

Comment: It would be helpful if someone can suggest a way to check in a topic that  the latest msg has been read using KafkaListener. Maybe by comparing offset and consumer offset. Or some other way.

Answer (score 2):

After the clarification in the comments this is, what I understand, what you want to achieve:

> You have a database like system, and the meta data from the kafka topic is used to adjust the table structure. Then the actual data comes into the master kafka topic which you then want to insert into the table. In other words: You want to define the structure of your data using kafka.

I am not sure, if that's what I would call a regular use case for Kafka, as it is meant to be an interface to exchange events, aka data. What you try to do, is to use the system as a means of defining data structure. But that's only my opinion.

As said earlier in the comments, there is practically no way to say that there won't be a message in one topic. You can only say: there is no message "yet". What you "could" probably do is: When a message in the `master` topic arrives, you first check the `meta` topic, if there is a message, too. If there is, you apply the changes in data structure, then import the message fron the master topic.

Another option would be to use Kafka Streams instead of the raw consumers 
to bring together the two topics, with a `join` for example.

Anyway to define the data structure, one would normally use something like Avro, which gives you schema evolution and more. Then write your application to be aware of schema changes an apply them to your database tables accordingly.

**UPDATE: How to solve using Kafka Streams**

As mentioned above, the use of Kafka Streams would be a possible solution to your case. Let me explain, what i mean in some pseudo kafka streams code:

```java
import org.apache.kafka.streams.StreamsBuilder;
import org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.GlobalKTable;

import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;

/**
 * Just an incomplete Kafka Streams Code Demo to show how the problem could
 * be solved with this framework instead of using the consumers directly.
 * Kafka Streams Boilerplate code not included.
 */
public class Example {
    private static final String META_TOPIC = "meta";
    private static final String MASTER_TOPIC = "master";

    // You have to make sure, the meta data is stored under this
    // specific key in the meta topic.
    private static final byte[] META_KEY = MetaEvent.class.getName().getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Example().createTopology();
    }

    public void createTopology() {

        final StreamsBuilder builder = new StreamsBuilder();

        final GlobalKTable<byte[], MetaEvent> metaTable = builder.globalTable(META_TOPIC);

        builder.<byte[], MasterEvent>stream(MASTER_TOPIC)
                .leftJoin(
                        metaTable,
                        (k, v) -> META_KEY,
                        MasterWithMeta::new)
                .foreach(this::handleEvent);
    }

    private void handleEvent(byte[] key, MasterWithMeta masterWithMeta) {
        // 1) check if meta has changed, if so, apply changes to database
        // 2) import master data to database
    }
}

class MasterWithMeta {
    private final MasterEvent master;
    private final MetaEvent meta;

    public MasterEvent getMaster() {
        return master;
    }

    public MetaEvent getMeta() {
        return meta;
    }

    public MasterWithMeta(MasterEvent master, MetaEvent meta) {
        this.master = master;
        this.meta = meta;
    }

    public static MasterWithMeta create(MasterEvent master, MetaEvent meta) {
        return new MasterWithMeta(master, meta);
    }
}

class MetaEvent {
    // ...
}

class MasterEvent {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Let me put my question this way. Is it possible to check if the latest message has been read from the topic using KafkaListeners.

Comment: You could probably check, if your current consumer lag, and if it is zero then you say, okay, nothing more to read, but that does not mean, that in 5ms there is not another update to the topic.

Another option could be, to set the consumer offset manually, but that does not seem to be a practical nor an indented way to use kafka.

With an framework like Kafka Streams however, you would have the opportunity to join two topics together AND treat the meta topic like a table, where you only get the latest record that is present at the time you join the meta on the master data.

Comment: I updated my answer to show, how this problem would be solved using Kafka Streams. You might give it a try.